# The elliptic integral $\frac{K'}{K}=\sqrt{2}-1$ is known in closed form?

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, modular-forms, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

Has anybody computed in closed form the elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k)$ when $\frac{K'}{K}=\sqrt{2}-1$?

I tried to search the literature, but nothing has turned up. This page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html cites several cases 
$\frac{K'}{K}=\sqrt{r}$, when $r$ is integer.

Update: This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557867/please-help-to-identify-this-numerical-constant/1574617#1574617).

Comment: Isn't it the case that $K'/K=\sqrt r$ by definition? Or am I misreading the page (at the bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If,

$$\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}=\sqrt{2}-1$$

then (in *Mathematica* or [Walpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5BModularLambda%5BSqrt%5B-2%5D-Sqrt%5B-1%5D%5D%5D) syntax),

$$k = \sqrt{\lambda(\tau)}=\sqrt{\text{ModularLambda[}\tau]}=0.9959420044834\dots$$

where $\tau = \sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-1},$ and $\lambda(\tau)$ is the [elliptic lambda function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html). See this [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574617/4781) for more details.