# Please, help to identify this numerical constant

Tags: numerical-methods, pattern-recognition, symbolic-computation, experimental-mathematics, inverse-problems

I'm trying to find an answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553708/the-elliptic-integral-frackk-sqrt2-1-is-known-in-closed-form). Let 
$K(k)$ be the elliptic integral of the first kind and $K'=K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$.
According to Abel's theorem (see this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)) we know that if $\frac{K'}{K}=\frac{a+b\sqrt{n}}{c+d\sqrt{n}}$ where $a,b,c,d,n$ are integers, then $k$ is the root of an algebraic equation with integer coefficients. (As I understand it, by algebraic equation with integer coefficients they mean a polynomial with integer coefficients?) So I solved the equation
$$
\displaystyle \frac{K(\sqrt{1-k^2})}{K(k)}=\sqrt{2}-1
$$
numerically with 200 digit accuracy and found the corresponding $k$:

> $$
> k=0.995942004483485267626221391206685115425856878468293704688032877263852669\\384783141641717390148240933985687938743309287701383005201421919573984016706\\406957193055047393475454459046127151355572762924
> $$

Here is the Mathematica code I used:

k:=Sqrt[m/.FindRoot[EllipticK[1 - m]/EllipticK[m] - Sqrt[ 2 ] +1==0,{m,1},WorkingPrecision -> 200]];
N[k,200]

(As was pointed out below by ccorn EllipticK(k^2)$=K(k)$.)

Then I tried to identify this algebraic constant by [Inverse symbolic calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) but it couldn't identify it. Is there some other way to identify this equation with integer coefficients?

Comment: The `Recognize[...]` command does not yield any likely candidates.

Comment: Isn't $m=k^2$ in Mathematica? Then you should use `1-m` instead of `Sqrt[1-m^2]` and take the squareroot of the $m$ you found.

Comment: Cf. [Wolfram's reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EllipticIntegralsAndEllipticFunctions.html) where they state that $K'(m) = K(1-m)$.

Comment: @ccorn thanks, I edited the question. But still inverse symbolic calculator couldn't recognize the corrected value of $k$.

Comment: @ccorn: From what you recall about the eta quotient $\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}$, does Part II of my answer hold true?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Yes, since $\frac{k^4}{1-k^2} = 256\left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^{24}$. I also doubt that $k$ is algebraic, and that Whittaker & Watson have forgotten some $\mathrm{i}$, but first I'd like to see the article by Abel which Whittaker & Watson seem to have referenced.

Comment: Mathworld references Whitaker & Watson, which archive.org has [online](https://archive.org/stream/courseofmodernan00whit#page/524/mode/2up). It's just a remark with an opaque reference to Abels *oeuvres* vol. I (published papers), the edition by Sophus Lie et al. Archive.org seems to only have the [earlier collection](https://archive.org/stream/oeuvrescomplte01abel#page/376/mode/2up), and I have not been able to identify Abel's article there.

Comment: If the reference is to Crelle, [this article](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0003&DMDID=DMDLOG_0018&LOGID=LOG_0018&PHYSID=PHYS_0192) might be it, but my french has been out of use for some decades, and I have difficulties identifying the symbols.

Comment: There is an 1881 article by Hurwitz [online](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01447295?no-access=true), where he recalls that, given period ratios $\omega$ and $\omega_1$, $k(\omega), k(\omega_1)$ are algebraically related if $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ satisfy $a\omega\omega_1+b\omega+c\omega_1+d=0$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $ad-bc>0$. No surprise there. Hurwitz essentially proves that this bilinear form in $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ is the only possible form of an algebraic relation between $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ whenever $k(\omega), k(\omega_1)$ are algebraically related.

Comment: @ccorn: Thanks for finding those references. I normally deal with $\tau$ that is a complex root of a quadratic, and I haven't really explored when it is a root of higher deg eqns.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I'm not into transcendence matters, but [we had such questions discussed in comments before](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/650391/75794) and found that when $\tau$ is algebraic of degree greater than 2, then $j$, and hence $k$, must be transcendental. Which means your answer here is right, and W&W must have got it slightly wrong. This time Mathworld is not to blame, they just copied the statement almost verbatim from W&W.

Comment: @ccorn: Oh, I remember that post now. Thanks for the clarification re Whittaker and Watson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think *Mathworld's* [explanation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) of *Abel's Theorem* is incomplete.

**Part I.** The *Mathematica* command is,

$$\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}=\frac{\text{EllipticK[1-ModularLambda[}\tau]]}{\text{EllipticK[ModularLambda[}\tau]]}=\sqrt{2}-1\tag1$$

where the argument $\tau$ is,

$$\color{brown}{\tau = \sqrt{-2}-\sqrt{-1}}\tag2$$

Thus, we get your constant,

$$k = \sqrt{\lambda(\tau)}=\sqrt{\text{ModularLambda[}\tau]}=0.9959420044834\dots\tag3$$

Other expressions are,

$$\big(\lambda(\tau)\big)^{1/8} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\,\eta(\tfrac{\tau}{2})\,\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta^3(\tau)} = \left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q)}{\vartheta_3(0,q)}\right)^{1/2} = \cfrac{\sqrt{2}\,q^{1/8}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+q+\cfrac{q^2}{1+q^2+\cfrac{q^3}{1+q^3+\ddots}}}}$$

with the *nome* $q = \exp(i \pi \tau)$, *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$, and *Jacobi theta function* $\vartheta_n(0,q)$, with both functions built in Mathematica. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541027/4781).

**Part II.** Now as to whether $k$ given by $(3)$ is algebraic, your question is equivalent to asking if the eta quotient,

$$x =\frac{\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\tag4$$

is algebraic.  If $\tau$ is an imaginary ***quadratic*** $\tau_2$, then it is *yes*. However, your $\tau$ is an imaginary ***quartic*** root $\tau_4$, a root of,

$$\color{brown}{\tau^4+6\tau^2+1 = 0}\tag5$$

**Conclusion:** I think Abel's Theorem covers only at most $\tau_2$, not $\tau_4$, and Mathworld forgot(?) that crucial detail. Re this comment in an [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210928/are-these-two-q-continued-fractions-equivalent#comment522845_210928).